# MySQL MIN query not working for calculated distance

Tags: mysql, database, geolocation

I have a table of locations in my database. I need a query to find out the nearest location, provided any coordinates. I wrote the following query to get all rows, along with their respective distance from a given coordinate(distance in meters):

```
SELECT *, 111111 * DEGREES(ACOS(LEAST(COS(RADIANS(dest.latitude)) * COS(RADIANS(8.584710)) * COS(RADIANS(dest.longitude - 76.868735)) + SIN(RADIANS(dest.latitude)) * SIN(RADIANS(8.584710)), 1.0))) as  distance FROM offer dest;
```

It gives the following output:

```
+----+------------------------+----------+-----------+------------+---------------------+
| id | description            | latitude | longitude | name       | distance            |
+----+------------------------+----------+-----------+------------+---------------------+
|  2 | Location 1 Description | 8.574858 | 76.874748 | Location 1 |   1278.565430298969 |
| 12 | Location 2 Description | 8.584711 | 76.868738 | Location 2 | 0.35494725284463646 |
+----+------------------------+----------+-----------+------------+---------------------+
```

It is all working fine. Now to get the Minimum distance, I added `HAVING MIN(distance)` to this query. Now the query looks like below:

```
SELECT *, 111111 * DEGREES(ACOS(LEAST(COS(RADIANS(dest.latitude)) * COS(RADIANS(8.584710)) * COS(RADIANS(dest.longitude - 76.868735)) + SIN(RADIANS(dest.latitude)) * SIN(RADIANS(8.584710)), 1.0))) as  distance FROM offer dest having MIN(distance);
```

Now, this query is supposed to return 1 row and that should be Location 2, as it has the the minimum location, but this is returning location 1 instead as seen below:

```
+----+------------------------+----------+-----------+------------+---------------------+
| id | description            | latitude | longitude | name       | distance            |
+----+------------------------+----------+-----------+------------+---------------------+
|  2 | Location 1 Description | 8.574858 | 76.874748 | Location 1 |   1278.565430298969 |
+----+------------------------+----------+-----------+------------+---------------------+
```

Why is this behaving so? Is there something wrong with my query? IF yes, what is it and how do I get the location with minimum distance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `HAVING`-clause is used to filter conditions for a group. A group is defined with an aggregate function in `SELECT`-part and with a `GROUP BY`. As you do not have either of those, you should not use `HAVING`.

If you want to show the minimum distance from set of rows order by the distance and limit the result set just to one row.

```
SELECT *, 
  111111 * DEGREES(ACOS(LEAST(COS(RADIANS(dest.latitude)) *
  COS(RADIANS(8.584710)) * COS(RADIANS(dest.longitude - 76.868735)) + 
  SIN(RADIANS(dest.latitude)) * SIN(RADIANS(8.584710)), 1.0))) as  distance
FROM offer dest 
ORDER BY distance
LIMIT 1;
```